# Call to a member function ratings() on null - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to rate a book, if the user has not rated already.

if the user has, redirect back to the page

so far i get

```
Call to a member function ratings() on null
```

i'm using [laravel rateable](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable)

Any suggestions on why its not working ?

**BookController.php**

```
public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
{

    $book = Book::find($book_id)->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

    $rating = new Rating();

    if(is_null($book)){
        $rating->rating =  $request['rating'];
        $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $book->ratings()->save($rating);
        return redirect()->back();

    }
    else{
        return redirect()->back()->with("You already made a review");
     }



}
```

**User.php(model)**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }



}
```

**Book.php**(model)

```
class Book extends Model
{

    use Rateable;

    protected $fillable = [ 'user_id', 'title', 'description'];


    public function scopeGetBook($query, $book_name )
    {
        return $query->where('slug',  $book_name )->first();
    }

    public function setTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value);

    }




    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

This works, however i need it only allow a user to do this method once, else redirect back to page. So if a user already made a rating redirect back to page other wise allow a user to make a rating.

```
   public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
    {

        $book = Book::find($book_id);
        $rating = new Rating();

        $rating->rating =  $request['rating'];
        $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $book->ratings()->save($rating);
        return redirect()->back();


    }
```

**schema**

```
class CreateRatingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->morphs('rateable');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->index('rateable_id');
            $table->index('rateable_type');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('ratings');
    }
}
```

Comment: post your model and migration as well.

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump() of $book prior to the null check?

Comment: i updated it, i get null on dd(book), which is what i want, if the user has not made a rating, then rate it, otherwise redirect back to back with a message.

Comment: `book` not `rating` ... if there is no `book` instance (`null`) what are you rating? one step at a time

Comment: for example there is a book instance for 

`$book = Book::find($book_id)->where('user_id',1)->first();`

Comment: but if another user try to make an instance

i get the Call to a member function ratings() on null

Comment: @BARNOWL Please show your User model

Comment: I just updated this

Comment: @BARNOWL Is there any rating table exists? If yes then show the table

Comment: it does exist, i updated it

Comment: why do you even add where(user_id) condition on book? by doing so only one user is allowed to query the book itself, this kinda makes no sense, does it?

Comment: then how would i check if the authenticated user already rated a book ?

Comment: @BARNOWL have you thought of checking the Rating? Not sure why you care who the current 'owner' of a book is in regards to random users being able to rate it.

Comment: you should query the ratings for the book and not the book itself, will provide anwers, maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add you where condition on the ratings and not the book:

```
// lets get the book the user would like to rate
$book = Book::find($book_id);

// now lets check if the currently authenticated user 
// has already created a ratings for this book:
// $book->ratings() will query all ratings for on current book
// ->where(...) will additionally reduce the result set to those ratings
// provided by the currently authenticated user
// ->first() will simply pick the first result if it exists
$rating = $book->ratings()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

// in case there is no rating allocated to the user and the book
// we can continue creating the new rating 
if(is_null($rating)){
    $rating = new Ratings()
    $rating->rating =  $request['rating'];
    $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $book->ratings()->save($rating);
    return redirect()->back();
}
else{
    return redirect()->back()->with("You already made a review");
}
```

Comment: will add some comments in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a Rating Model named `Rating.php` and paste this code

```
/**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function rateable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'rateable_id', 'rateable_type', 'rating', 'user_id',
    ];
```

Add this in your book model

```
public function ratings() {
        return $this->morphMany(Rating::class, 'rateable')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    }
```

You don't need to add `$table->morphs('rateable')` so remove it from migration.

Hopefully this code will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following says, run this block of code if `$book` IS `null`:

```
if(is_null($book)){
    $rating->rating =  $request['rating'];
    $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $book->ratings()->save($rating);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

You are guaranteed that `$book` is `null`. So you are using `$book` like an object when it is `null`.

```
$a = null;
$a->blah();
```

You probably want:

```
if (! is_null($book)) {
```

That was in respect to "Any suggestions on why its not working ?".

```
Book::find($book_id)->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
```

If `find` doesn't return a Model this breaks. When find does return a model, this is just used as a means of creating a new builder instance and executing a new query. The result of `find(...)`, the Book, is thrown out.

```
// previous chain of statements results in this
Book::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
```

I guess this means only a Book that isn't owned by the current User?

I am going to just assume you mean to check a Rating instead

```
public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
{
    $book = Book::findOrFail($book_id);

    $user_id = $request->user()->id;

    if (! $book->ratings()->where('user_id', $user_id)->exists()) {
        // create new rating for this book by this user
        $rating = new Rating;

        ...

        $book->ratings()->save($rating);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    // you have already rated this book
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to rate a book, if the user has not rated it already.

if the user has, redirect back to the page

thank you, however it redirected back to the page without leaving a rating.

Comment: i want to leave a rating, and redirect back if the user has made a review already

Comment: thanks for your feedback, however im getting 

`General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value` `insert into 
 `ratings`